# PHP: member functions can't access member variables

Tags: php, class

I'm experimenting with PHP classes and I've created this simple class:

```
<?php

  /* email.php

    Returns a wrapper object that handles the sending of an email

  */

  class Email 
  {
    private $message = "";
    private $subject = "";
    private $to = "";

    public function setMessage(string $newMessage) {
      $this->$message = $newMessage;
    }

    public function setSubject(string $newSubject) {
      $this->$subject = $newSubject;
    }

    public function setRecipient(string $newRecipient) {
      $this->$to = $newRecipient;
    }

    public function send() {
      mail($this->$to, $this->$subject, $this->$message);
    }
  }

  $email = new Email();
  $email->setRecipient('test@gmail.com');
  $email->setSubject('A message');
  $email->setMessage('Does this work?');
  $email->send();

?>
```

However, when I run this (I am calling this script via a fetch request on my fronted), I get the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: to in /home/jack/Projects/test/php/email.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined variable: subject in /home/jack/Projects/test/php/email.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined variable: message in /home/jack/Projects/test/php/email.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined variable: to in /home/jack/Projects/test/php/email.php on line 28

Notice: Undefined variable: subject in /home/jack/Projects/test/php/email.php on line 28

Notice: Undefined variable: message in /home/jack/Projects/test/php/email.php on line 28
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The proper syntax to access a property is `$this->propertyName`, not `$this->$propertyName`. Drop those dollar signs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're doing `$this->$subject`, you mean `$this->subject`.

Fuller answer:

PHP allows you to have custom variable names. E.g. you could set

```
$i = 0;

$var$i = "abc";
```

Then `$var0` would contain "abc".